# Python: Is there a simple way to address the component functions of a list/array valued function?

Tags: python, list, function

Say I have a function `f(t)` which returns values in an list. Let me symbolically write the return list as `[f0(t),f1(t),...]`, but this shouldn't mean that I have those component functions `f0,f1,...` defined anywhere.

I would like to define them however!

Of course one way would be

```
def f0(t): return f(t)[0]
def f1(t): return f(t)[1]
...
```

however I suspect that there must be a more elegant way to do this. Is there?

Thanks for suggestions!

(Just as side information: In my case the function `f(t)` is the solution function of an initial value problem obtained with `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` and the `dense_output` option. [link to documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html))

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. It really helps if you give a concrete example.

Comment: So, in your example `solve_ivp` is your `f(t)` .. right?

Comment: what's wrong with `f(t)[0]` directly?

Comment: It alrady exists: [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

Comment: @Anwarvic, if we name the output `return = solve_ivp(*args, **kwargs)`, then my function `f = return.sol`. Important for this function to be given out is that the key-word argument `dense_output=True`.

Comment: @adrtam I had the suspicion that with `f(t)[0]`, it would compute the full output array every time I define such a component function. And that seemed like a waste. So I thought there must be a smarter way to do it, avoiding repeated calculations of the same thing. See also the answer by @chepner below.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I am not sure if this is what I need yet, but I will have a closer look into it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK repeating the call to `f(t)` for different values of `n`, I would just define a two-argument wrapper around `f`:

```
def fresult(t, n):
    return f(t)[n]
```

However, you probably *don't* want to recompute `f(t)` many times. In that case, you can cache the return value.

```
def make_getter(f):
    cache = {}
    def _(t, n):
        if t not in cache:
            cache[t] = tuple(f(t))
        return cache[t][n]
    return _

fresult = make_getter(f)
assert fresult(t, 1) == f(t)[1]
```

Comment: Hi @chepner, thanks for your answer! The idea was indeed to *not* compute all components of the value of `f(t)`, every time I define a component function. So what you suggest sounds like what I wanted. But I do not understand the code you wrote, and it doesn't run on my system. In particular I do not understand the `def _(t,n)` inside the `make_getter` function. It appears to me that `_` is never called. Additional question: The name `_` is just a name, it has no specific function, right?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot the most important part, which is that `make_getter` has to *return* the function `_`.  I used `_` as the name because the local name isn't important.

Comment: Each time a new `_` is defined, it is associated with a fresh `cache` dict and the function `f` passed to `make_getter`. It is this function that gets bound to `fresult`, so that `fresult` either looks up a previously computed value of `f(t)` in its own copy of `cache`, or it calls `f(t)` and stores that value in `cache` before returning.

Comment: We call `_` a *closure* over both `cache` and `f`.  You can even see them stored in `fresult`, e.g. using `[x.cell_contents for x in fresult.__closure__]`.